# Finding the optimal weights to place on $n$ estimators to create a weighted-average that minimizes the expected squared error

Tags: matrices, parameter-estimation, mean-square-error

Consider $n$ independent random variables; $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$, each of which are estimators of a criterion $Y$.

$X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ may have different (known) variances, and may have different (known) biases in relation to $Y$.

What weights $w_1, w_2, ... w_n$ should be placed on $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ to create a weighted-average (i.e., an aggregate estimator) that minimizes the expected squared error?

A reference that deals with this (exact) problem, or better still, a demonstration of the solution, would be much appreciated. I have managed to find the solution for $n = 2$. However, the math for $n > 2$ becomes tedious - I suspect it requires the use of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. Here is my attempt.

Write, $Z = w_1X_1 + \cdots + w_nX_n$.

We would like to solve,
\begin{align*}
\min_{w_i}
\mathbb{E}[(Z-Y)^2] 
&= \min_{w_i} \mathbb{E}[Z^2] + \mathbb{E}[Y^2] - 2 \mathbb{E}[Z] \mathbb{E}[Y]
\\&= \min_{w_i} \mathbb{V}[Z] + \mathbb{V}[Y] + (\mathbb{E}[Z] - \mathbb{E}[Y])^2
\end{align*}

Taking the derivative with respect to $w_i$ and setting it to zero we have,
$$
w_i\mathbb{V}[X_i] + \left(\sum_j w_j \mathbb{E}[X_j] - \mathbb{E}[Y]\right) \mathbb{E}[X_i] = 0
$$
where we have used,
$$
\mathbb{E}[Z] = w_1 \mathbb{E}[X_1] + \cdots + w_n \mathbb{E}[X_n]
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{V}[Z] = w_1^2 \mathbb{V}[X_1] + \cdots + w_n^2 \mathbb{V}[X_n]
$$

Note that this is a linear system of equations in $w_i$: $
(\operatorname{diag}(V) + EE^T)w = \mathbb{E}[Y] E
$
where $V$ and $E$ are the vectors of variances and means of $X$.

In matrix form,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{V}[X_1]+\mathbb{E}[X_1]^2 & \mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_2] & \cdots & \mathbb{E}[X_1]\mathbb{E}[X_n] \\
\mathbb{E}[X_2]\mathbb{E}[X_1] & \mathbb{V}[X_2]+ \mathbb{E}[X_2]^2& \cdots & \mathbb{E}[X_2]\mathbb{E}[X_n] \\
\vdots & & \ddots\\
\mathbb{E}[X_n]\mathbb{E}[X_1] & \mathbb{E}[X_n]\mathbb{E}[X_2] & \cdots & \mathbb{V}[X_2]+\mathbb{E}[X_n]^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w_1 \\ w_2\\\vdots \\ w_n
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[X_1]\\
\mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[X_2]\\
\vdots \\
\mathbb{E}[Y]\mathbb{E}[X_n]
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So I guess if this system has a solution it should give a local extrema or saddle point to the minimization problem. Note that $V+EE^T$ is positive semidefinite which probably implies this is a minima (although my calculus is rusty).

In particular, if $\mathbb{V}[X_i] > 0$ for all $i$ then the system is positive definite so a unique solution is guranteed.

Comment: Supposing the expected value of the criterion is 0 (i.e., E[Y] = 0), then your solution appears to state that all weights are zero. That doesn't seem correct.

Comment: You need to normalize the weights, setting $Z=(w_1X_1+...+w_nX_n)/(w_1+...+w_n)$ should do it. Alternatively you can impose the additional condition that the weights sum to 1.

Comment: Why does all the weights being zero seem wrong? Then you're just saying to guess the zero random variable as the estimator for something with mean zero (in fact this is the best possible independent estimator for a mean zero RV). I agree additional conditions on the weights might make sense, but the natural condition given by @quarague would limit the mean of $Z$ to within the min and max of the means of the $X_i$.

Comment: If I add a 1 by $n$ vector of ones at the bottom of the first matrix, a $n$ by 1 vector to its right, and add a zero in its lowest right-hand corner, and I furthermore add a one at the bottom of the vector to the right of the equal-sign, then I obtain what I was looking for.

Comment: @tch do you agree that my amendment (shown in my comment above) adds the restriction that the sum of weights equals one?

Comment: Yeah, that would give the system you are looking for. However, now you will have more equations than unknowns, so it may be possible that you will not be able to solve the system.